# Transition Matrix in Dataframe Not Passing the Value

Tags: python, matrix, pandas

I am trying to implement transition matrix.

Both data and transition matrix are in DataFrames using Pandas

```
states_mat = pd.DataFrame(None, index=range(0,24), columns=range(0,24))
def states_update(data):

 states_vec = data['hr']
 # Do nothing if there is no sequence
 if len(states_vec) < 2:
     return

 for i in xrange(1, len(states_vec)):
     prev = states_vec[i-1]
     curr = states_vec[i]
     states_mat[curr][prev] += 1
```

Data are in int64 type

It is not updating +1 count as I wanted. I believe it is some kind of type issue, but not sure how to force the type. I am using DataFrame for my data as I want to use group function to split the data and apply the above function. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are doing chained indexing which may or may not work use `.loc` so try `states_mat.loc[curr, prev] += 1`, the other thing is that adding `1` to `NaN` is meaningless, you should set the default value to 0 so `states_mat = pd.DataFrame(0, index=range(0,24), columns=range(0,24))` so that you can then do the assignment `states_mat[curr][prev] += 1`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just figured it out too... it should have been 0 rather than none in making dataframe..

Comment: If this resolves your answer then I can post a full explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so the first problem and the one that resolved your issue is that you created your `states_mat` dataframe with a default value of `None` which becomes a `numpy.NaN`.

You cannot add an integer to a `NaN`:

```
In [24]:

NaN + 1
Out[24]:
nan
```

So change the DataFrame construction to:

```
states_mat = pd.DataFrame(0, index=range(0,24), columns=range(0,24))
```

Probably subindexing is fine in this case but you could have used `loc` also would work:

```
states_mat.loc[curr, prev] += 1
```